# Order by Count(field) but with all rows in the answer

Tags: mysql, count

I rewrite a stackoverflow question:

I have a table and data like this:

```
ID |  Name  |  Type 

1    Apple     A    

2    Boy       A

3    Cat       B

4    Dog       C

5    Elep      C

6    Fish      C
```

What SELECT I must use to obtain this result:

```
4    Dog       C

5    Elep      C

6    Fish      C

1    Apple     A    

2    Boy       A

3    Cat       B
```

I dont want this one ...:

```
select ID, Name, Type from TABLE where GROUP BY Type order by count(*) desc;
```

...whith this result:

```
4    Dog       C

1    Apple     A    

3    Cat       B
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you've got is the grouping command affects the values you are trying to select. One way around this is to derive the count (`typetotal`) for each `type`, in its own table like:

```
SELECT
      Type,
     COUNT(*) AS typetotal
    FROM
      TABLE
    GROUP BY
      Type
```

We are now able to link the `Type` to the `typetotal` to your new SELECT query using the `INNER JOIN` command, allowing you to sort the query as shown below:

```
SELECT
  TABLE.ID,
 TABLE.Name
 TABLE.Type,
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      Type,
     COUNT(*) AS typetotal
    FROM
      TABLE
    GROUP BY
      Type
  )
  AS tblTypeCount
  INNER JOIN
    TABLE
    ON
      TABLE.Type = tblTypeCount.Type
ORDER BY
  tblTypeCount.typetotal DESC
```

I hope I've explained this in a way that makes sense, if you need any clarification, or have any suggestions let me know.

Comment: Thank you very mutch scryptonight. It works fine for me.

Comment: Glad to hear it helps, if you're happy with the answer feel free to mark it as accepted *[here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)* for more info, unless of course you are still looking for an alternative method